# Ошибка при сборке проекта unity?

Tags: unity3d

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <50f55621a2ca4f31a35283e2979a8bf5>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <50f55621a2ca4f31a35283e2979a8bf5>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Несколько раз пересобрал, все равно эта ошибка.

Comment: Конечно легче просто поставить минус вопросу, чем сказать в чём его некорректность.

Comment: вы в вопросе предоставили только дефолтные отписки юнити - он их выдает всегда, когда билд фейлится. Ваши конкретные ошибки должны быть далее в консоли. В текущем состоянии на вопрос ответить невозможно